# How effectively does your squad use grenades?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Reading the answers to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54297/has-the-suicidal-squad-mate-ai-behavior-on-higher-difficulties-been-fixed) have me a *little* wary about investing in grenades for my squadmates. Your squad never had access to grenades in the first 2 games, so I'm unsure as to whether or not it's a power worth investing in for those squadmates who can use them.

Do you need to micromanage grenade use (like Stasis in ME1), or will squadmates use them as long as you have "Squadmate Power Use" for them turned on? I so far haven't been micromanaging my squad as much as I did in the previous game (though I'm only on Hardcore right now, not Insanity), and if I need to heavily micro the grenade powers, I'm not sure I want to invest in them at this point.

Will squadmates actively use grenades to try to push enemies out of cover, stagger Guardians with shields, or blow up Engineer turrets, or are they just kind of haphazard with them? For example, the radius on Sticky Grenades is fairly low, so will Garrus take that into account or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't use grenades at all unless directed to do so. Grenades are finite. Their aim is kind of bad, but if the squadmate is not seen by the player, the explosion will happen immediately and with perfect precision, unless the enemy is in cover.

Grenades are valuable because you can use them while other powers are in cooldown, which can be a lifesaver.

Comment: There's a difference in time before detonation that varies by whether or not your squaddie is in line of sight? What happens if they *are* in LOS?

Comment: What do you mean their aim is bad? When you order them to use powers they aim exactly where you target, is this not the case with grenades? Or do they just have crappy throwing arms?

Comment: @BenBrocka in my experienced, squadmates observed by the player will go through the motions associated with the chosen power (lean out of cover, wave their hands, etc), while those that aren't visible will immediately affect the target.

Answer (score 3):

Grenades are just like any other squad power, excepting their finite quantity.

That is to say, when used by squadmates, they have a longer cooldown and instantly hit their targets when used. For this reason, squadmates who use grenades are extremely accurate, as long as Shepard has a clear line of sight in the first place.

In terms of squad members using grenades on their own, I don't believe they ever will, even though they're on a separate cooldown.

So yes, you will have to micromanage your squad's grenades. On the bright side, when Shep picks up a grenade, it refills his squadmates as well.

Comment: Do squad mates throw grenades in a straight line at enemies or in an arc?

Comment: Neither. It just sort of magically appears and explodes directly on the target.

Comment: @Sterno ahah, so they're Longbow Grenades :)